# How to iterate through a hash of hashes which contains an array of hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, iteration

I am getting an output to a query in the format below. I need to get all the values for `itemthree`.

After trying a lot of different things I was able to extract only the first value. I couldn't figure out how to run it in a loop so as to get the values of all `itemthree` in the `items`  element.

This is a dump of my data

```
$VAR1 = {

    one => { msgSize => 103 },

    two => {
        items => [
            { itemOne => -1, itemthree => "AB_CD_EF", itemtwo => 0 },
            { itemOne => -1, itemthree => "XY_YZ_AB", itemtwo => 10 },
        ],
    },

    someOtherStuff => "abc",
}
```

Comment: Are you using `XML::Simple`?

Comment: Working with nested data structures in Perl is a very useful skill to pick up, I recommend the [perlreftut dcocumentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) that ships with Perl.  However, if you are trying to use XML::Simple as @Borodin and I suspect then I recommend you save yourself pain by following this [XML::LibXML tutorial](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) instead.

Comment: I am just getting started with Perl so this kind of study material will be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a hash:

```
my @item3s;

for my $item (@{ $hash{two}{items} }){
    push @item3s, $item->{itemthree};
}

print "$_\n" for @item3s;
```

If it's in fact a hash reference, change `$hash{two}{items}` to `$hash->{two}{items}`

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark if it helped you solve the problem.

Comment: @jaySingh: While "it worked" may result in an encouraging "yay!", it is important that you understand what is going on and *why* that solution worked. Perl code is transparent and intelligible, and it is wrong to treat a program as a kind of "password" that lets you into the behaviour you're looking for. It's very like natural language. I am sure you'd be ecstatic to be able to order double whiskey in Mesopotamia, but it's an empty achievement because you have to start all over again to ask for two double vodkas, one without ice. If you learned the Sumerian language then everything would flow

Comment: I understand. Thanks!